# `titlesec` and `memoir` class incompability

Tags: table-of-contents, memoir, titlesec

I know that `titlesec` is not fully compatible with `memoir` document class and generally it is not a good idea to combine them.
However, I'm just curious, if it possible to work around my problem.
MWE:

```
 \documentclass{memoir}
 \usepackage{titlesec}

 \titleformat{\part}[display]{}
 {\filcenter \Huge Part {\thepart}:}
 {20pt}{\Huge\bfseries\filcenter}

 \titleformat{\chapter}[display]{}
 {\filcenter \Huge Chapter {\thechapter}:}
 {20pt}{\Huge\bfseries\filcenter}

 \renewcommand\cftpartname{Part~}
 \renewcommand\cftchaptername{Chapter~}

 \begin{document}
 \tableofcontents
 \part{Abcdefghij}
 \chapter{chapter title}
 \part{Abcdefghij}

 \end{document}
```

If you compile this, commands which are related to chapters, sections, subsections like `\renewcommand\cftchaptername{Chapter~}` work fine, i.e. they set corresponding options inside ToC.
However any setting (e.g. `\renewcommand\cftpartname{Part~}`)  related to `\part` don't work at all.
Is it possible to "bypass" these settings to `part`?
I'm also interest in adding `\Romanbar{\thepart}` from package `romanbar` in `part` numbers (especially in ToC).
Thanks in advance!

Comment: It is a well-known fact actually, that `memoir` and `titlesec` are not really compatible. Use one of them, but not both.

Comment: And perhaps explain what you're trying to achieve with titlesec, then we might be able to find a memoir based solution