# memoir + titlesec: change the shape of subsection

Tags: memoir, titlesec

I have the following setup:

```
\documentclass{memoir}
\usepackage[sc]{titlesec} % "sc" to make titles small cap

\setsecnumdepth{subsection} % to number up to subsection

\hangsecnum % to make the numbers hanging in the margin

\begin{document}
    \chapter{Test chapter}
    \section{Test chapter}
    \subsection{Test chapter}
\end{document}
```

That is, I would like the chapter and section titles to be in small caps (`sc` option)
and be in the margin (`hangsecnum`). At the same time, I would like the subsections to be in italic.
How to achieve this?

Comment: Use `\titleformat*{\subsection}{\itshape}`.

Comment: This worked. If you make this an answer, I'd accept. Thanks.

Comment: See https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/467595/titlesec-and-memoir-class-incompability and https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/33012/4427

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the documentation,, in the *Quick reference* section, you simply have to type

```
\titleformat*{\subsection}{\itshape}
```

Of course, if you have more complex requirements, you might have to use the  *Advanced interface*.

Answer (score 4):

The package `titlesec` is not compatible with `memoir`. See [`titlesec` and `memoir` class incompability](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/467595/titlesec-and-memoir-class-incompability) and [About memoir and titlesec incompatibility](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/33012/4427)

You can obtain the wanted effect with `memoir` tools.

```latex
\documentclass{memoir}

\setsecnumdepth{subsection} % to number up to subsection

\renewcommand{\chapnamefont}{\normalfont\huge\scshape}
\renewcommand{\chapnumfont}{\normalfont\huge\scshape}
\renewcommand{\chaptitlefont}{\normalfont\Huge\scshape}

\setsecheadstyle{\Large\scshape\memRTLraggedright}
\setsubsecheadstyle{\large\itshape\memRTLraggedright}
\setsecnumformat{\makebox[0pt][r]{\upshape\csname the#1\endcsname\quad}}
% or just \hangsecnum if you want the number to inherit the same font as the title

\begin{document}

\chapter{Test chapter}
\section{Test section}
\subsection{Test subsection}

\end{document}
```

[image]

If you want that the numbers are inside the margin, you can do

```
\documentclass{memoir}

\setsecnumdepth{subsection} % to number up to subsection

\renewcommand{\chapnamefont}{\normalfont\huge\scshape}
\renewcommand{\chapnumfont}{\normalfont\huge\scshape}
\renewcommand{\chaptitlefont}{\normalfont\Huge\scshape}

\setsecheadstyle{\Large\scshape\memRTLraggedright}
\setsubsecheadstyle{\large\itshape\memRTLraggedright}
\setsecnumformat{\makebox[3pc][l]{\upshape\csname the#1\endcsname\quad}}

\begin{document}

\chapter{Test chapter}
\section{Test section}
\subsection{Test subsection}

\end{document}
```

[image]

You might need to adjust the fixed 3pc space to fit big numbers.

Comment: I had to use `titlesec` for some other non-trivial function. But I agree that `memoir` has all the features on might wish for.

Comment: Thanks for this answer! Do you know how one might keep the numbers aligned with the text rather than in the margin but while keeping the titles of the section/subsection aligned? (Like in [this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TLRqd.png).) Thank you!

Comment: @LinoFerreira Are you using `memoir`?

Comment: Hi @egreg, yes I am!

Comment: @LinoFerreira So you want the same as in the answer, but with the numbers inside the margin?

Comment: Yes, please! The challenge is that then the two titles (the words "Test section" and "Test subsection") may not be aligned vertically (at least this was the issue I ran into when I tried adapting your code -- see [here](https://imgur.com/jtgC4hX)). Thanks!

Comment: @LinoFerreira Added in the answer

Comment: This is perfect, thank you so much!